# Перформанс браузера: div или td?

Tags: производительность, html, браузер

В одностраничном приложении генерятся данные, внешне похожие на таблицу. В `<div>`'е с прокруткой несколько столбцов цифр, сгруппированных по дням. Разной высоты. Пока я сделал каждую "ячейку" абсолютно спозиционированным `<div>`'ом:

[image: так выглядит]

Выясняется, что ячеек в некоторых случаях может быть много, несколько тысяч. Браузер заметно, порядка 2-3 секунд, тормозит, пока генерирует их (backbone), но, в каком именно месте основные тормоза, я пока не выяснил.

Посмотрел на днях исходник GMail – там `<table>` для списка писем.

Есть ли заметные преимущества в рендеринге браузером ячеек таблицы перед отдельными абсолютно спозиционированными `<div>`'ами, учитывая, что длинная таблица прячется в коротком контейнере с прокруткой?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А какая религия запрещает пользоваться профайлером? Но непонятно, почему это делать абсолютно позионированными div? Тормоза, скорее всего, в генераторе. Вы прям в документ пишете элементы по одному или сначала элемент общий собираете?

**Обновление**

Попробуйте вставлять не в документ, а в созданный элемент, а потом уже элемент вставляйте. Ну и подумайте - может события можно всплывающими сделать вместо слушателя на каждый. Параметры в data атрибутах.

Comment: @eicto, профайлер показывает тормоза во внутренностях underscore. Ещё пороюсь поглубже, спасибо.

Вероятно, тормоза и от индивидуального `append()` каждого из div'ов (каждый - backbone view). Как бы их собрать вместе и только потом вставить одним append'ом? У каждого события.

Answer (score 0):

> Пока я сделал каждую "ячейку" абсолютно спозиционированным `<div>`'ом:

Миллиард абсолютно позиционированных элементов - это сразу беда, как минимум при любой прокрутке окна, хотя думаю, что и без того это не очень полезно.
Если у вас таблица, то, по-моему, лучше сразу рисовать таблицей, а вот если там перформанс просядет - уже смотреть варианты.